# How to get password for Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, users, boot-loader, access-control

Good day

I think my friend is running li**nux on my home PC and Android Samsung S7 phone.

Is it possible?

How can I check if its running?

Can I get access to the account on the PC or Phone without his password?

R
Oscar

Comment: you are asking about full access to what? ... laptop or phone?

Comment: English is probably not your native language, and you need to put some more effort into writing sentences that express what you want. Currently, we can only guess that you somehow want to run Linux but it's unclear what your friend, his password, or your android phone have got to do with it. If it's your own home PC, install Linux on it, there are thousands of tutorials all over the internet.

Comment: Hey jsotola. For now only the phone I haven't really been on the laptop.

Comment: Thx Hans. I'll will do that.

Comment: I have a Samsung S7 and it look like he installed an Easter egg on my phone.

Comment: Maybe it's /e/ os https://e.foundation/ https://e.foundation/products/#ecosystem which as per https://doc.e.foundation/devices/#smartphone-build-branch-details has a build for the Samsung S7.

Comment: The title is not in line with the question.  The question asks "how can I get full access to the Linux installed on my laptop and phone" (this is a question about recovering a root password, and possibly about rooting the phone). The title asks how to _install_ Linux. There is no indication _what_ Linux is running on the laptop, or what's running on the phone (you say Android, but also say that "your friend is running Linux on the phone", whatever that means). Please clarify your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many versions of Linux. You can see which version of the Linux 'kernel' that PC runs by opening a terminal window and running

```
lsb_release -a && uname -a
```

'Linux' properly is the kernel of the operating system, over which [GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) packages of apps and programs run. There's almost always a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) or [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) which makes the system much more Windows-like or Mac-like, and easier to use. All of those together are a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) AKA 'distro'.

One distro, "Ubuntu", is very popular and has support at another StackExchange Q&A site, http://askubuntu.com

You can download the ISO file of Ubuntu Linux for PC desktops at https://ubuntu.com/download   or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu  .

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu  or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows  .

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it on your laptop following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop  .